Ubuntu upgradation problem
I have been using Ubuntu in my home desktop pc for my personal use since last 4+ years. Last week, as soon as i booted my pc, i got a pop up message to upgrade the Ubuntu to its latest version (i guess its V24.0), i was using Ubuntu version 22.0.
The ugrade started & the files were downloaded & the next step was to download the files. The download started & it got stuck in the middlle, the terminal box was showing about some clash with the current Thunderbird version. I waited for quite sometime & unfortunately, there was a power outage & the UPS backup also died down & the pc shut. The next day, i switched on the pc, but i am getting a blank screen after the initial green bootup page. I dont understand what is happening, kindly help & provide me with the required supprt.
I did leave a message on the canonical ubuntu support page, i did get an email response from one Naveen K Jaisappan, but once i detailed my probem, i did not get the required solution to my problem.
Kindly help...
Regards
Bharath

Please be precise with details; Ubuntu releases are year.month in format showing when the product is released; Ubuntu had releases in April & October in 2022; thus there is 22.04 (2022-April) & 22.10 (2022-October) but 0 is not a valid month (you mention 22.0 - are you using Ubuntu? or just didn't include all details).

My apologies Sir for the inconvenience, maybe i did not get the version right.  The version you have mentioned is right, i got it wrong.

As mentioned earlier, my problem started when i recieved a pop-up message on booting Ubuntu (Mate) that a new release has been released (i remember reading the version starting from 24, the rest i dont remember) & i confirmed to upgrade the current version. It took about 30-40 min to download the upgrade files & post downloading, the terminal box opened & the installation of the downloaded files started. After sometime, the installation came to a standstill with the Thunderbird files extraction. I waited for 30 min, the installation did not proceed further. Rest is mentioned in the 1st msg.

Hi, Can anyone help ???

Your details are very unclear; Ubuntu releases are year.month in format so 22.0 & 24.0 is invalid.   You likely mean 22.04 (2022-April release) & 24.04 (2024-April release) as that is a supported upgrade path; however if that wasn't what you were using; any provided help will unlikely help you as have other issues... If you have a Canonical contract for support why not just use that as your question implies; they'll have details of what you run, as you've not said here giving only invalid details (24.10 is the latest; upgrades are from 24.04; ie. April to October update)

In your case; I'd treat the last issue which was the power outage.  I'd boot a live system and perform file-system checks of your installed systems partitions (command will vary on your unstated file-systems)... If any issues are detected & fixed you'll have more successful boot next try.. Next I'd boot to runlevel 1 or recovery & see if all is good...  then try and continue boot to a text login only (ie. avoid GUI)... check what system reports as (lsb_release -a) etc then explore sources (cat /etc/apt/sources.list etc) then update software lists (sudo apt update), apply upgrades etc
